# some details of Differential Evolution

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I use NMinimze Function with method Differential Evolution method, to get the optimal solution
I don't give any parameters for this method, I accept the default values that mathematica gives
as follows

```
NMinimize[{x-y, 0<=x<=100, y>=100}, {x,y} \[Element] Integers,
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

Method Differential Evolution work on population and apply cross operations and mutation to search for the best solution.
I want to ask that after evaluation finishes can I know the popualtion that gives this solution??
thank you.